# PHP md5 and sha1 confusion - Why am I getting different encryption results?

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, md5, sha1

I have a php function in a php page called encrypt_password that I use when processing a registration form:

```
function encrypt_password($password){

    $salt  = sha1(md5($password));
    $password = md5($password.$salt);

    return $password;
}
```

I try to use it again for when I process the login form but I get a different result.

I get the correct result just by not calling this function and instead just calling:

```
$salt  = sha1(md5($password));
$password = md5($password.$salt);
```

directly on my process_login page. Why would I get a different result by calling encrypt_password?

I hope I have explained this clearly enough!
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you would. Can you show a bit more code, please?

Comment: [Looks fine to me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nlSYuW)... Maybe you should supply it with the same password each time ;)

Comment: Why not show some examples for all the values, instead of arguing?

Comment: Regardless of the source of your bug, you appear to generate a "salt" by hashing the password. Be aware that this is not a salt and is utterly weak against attacks (this is totally open to attacks with precomputed tables, such as "rainbow tables", the very thing that a real salt would thwart, and your not-salt does not). Also, your password-hashing scheme uses only three nested hash invocations, and that's just more weakness (you should have thousands, even millions of invocations here). Use [bcrypt](http://yorickpeterse.com/articles/use-bcrypt-fool/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply cannot believe this to be true. You say you have two pages, one with a registration form and one with a login form.

They both have to encrypt the password the user has posted.

There can be a number of things wrong here, depending on how you find they don't match. Do you just try to login and see an error that your password is wrong? Or did you echo the password hash after a call to `encrypt_password`? It would be nice to have done that to shown us a hash of the password 'test', from both the registration page and the login page. Perhaps someone could've seen a pattern.

Anyway, let me guess:

1. You enter the password incorrectly.
2. You have created this user you're testing it with, with an older version of your encryption function. Perhaps you only used `md5(password)` to register, then you read somewhere that was unsafe and added a salt. Now you're comparing two different hashes for the same password, since the password is stored in the database using the old hashing function.
3. You set `$password` with `$password = $_POST['password'];` I guess. On both pages, I guess too. Are those statements on both pages typo-free? No `$password = $_POST['pasword'];` there? And are both `<input>` elements named "password"?
4. Typos also go for the $encrypt_password function. Do you define it on both pages, or do you include it from another file? (You should!) If they exist in both files, do they match letter by letter? Copypaste it to test this, and if it works, thank me and put it in an include afterwards, and let it be a lesson.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem .
check the length of password field in db the value after hashed is increased the limit you specified in the db

Answer (score -2):

Yep, I checked the code and theres is no error. This is my code without any flaws:

```
 function encrypt_password($password){
        $salt  = sha1(md5($password));
        $password = md5($password.$salt);
        return $password;
}

$myPassword = "test";
echo encrypt_password($myPassword );
// this gives me 34364c859afb02e70306c905374ac2d5

$salt  = sha1(md5($myPassword));
$password = md5($myPassword.$salt);
echo "<br />";

echo $password;
//this gives me 34364c859afb02e70306c905374ac2d5
```

So, they are the same. Like Dimme, I thought the same about variable names. But I could not replicate this. Sorry...

Comment: Remember one thing that once happened with me in the past. Somehow, I was passing an extra space on the password field. Try to echo the variables that you're passing through the form.

Comment: You don't provide any solution. Besides that, your code might not look exactly the same as user1050479's.

Comment: LOL. I copied yours... you are the one with this issue, not me... or Dimme